# Pythonファイルを実行した際の「jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '>'」というエラー

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, flask

初めまして。私は現在Python及びTensorFlowを用いて、個人の趣味で画像認識のWebアプリを開発している者なのですが、実際に以下のWeb実行用ファイル(記述はPython)を実行するとJinja2のエラーが発生してどうすればよいのかわかりません。
なお、使用しているソフトウェアはPycharm(Community Edition 2018.1.4)で、実行も同様のソフトウェアを使用しています。OSはWindows10です。また、Anaconda3も使用しています。
以下は元のプログラム（Web用）のコードです。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing as mp
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import numpy as np
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os
import eval

# 自身の名称を app という名前でインスタンス化する
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
# 投稿画像の保存先
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/images/default'

# ルーティング。/にアクセス時
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

# 画像投稿時のアクション
@app.route('/post', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if not request.files['file'].filename == u'':
      # アップロードされたファイルを保存
      f = request.files['file']
      img_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, secure_filename(f.filename))
      f.save(img_path)
      # eval.pyへアップロードされた画像を渡す
      result = eval.evaluation(img_path, './model2.ckpt')
    else:
      result = []
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
  else:
    # エラーなどでリダイレクトしたい場合
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.debug = True
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\SUPERGTgazouhanbetu\flask\app.py",     line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\web.py", line 20, in index
return render_template('index.html')
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Tensorflow\gazouhanbetu\templates\index.html", line 198, in template
{% if result[0][0]['label'] == 6 %>
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 497, in _parse
return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 901, in parse
result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 268, in parse_block
node.body = self.parse_statements(('name:endblock',), drop_needle=True)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
'name:endif'))
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
'name:endif'))
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
'name:endif'))
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
      File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 213, in parse_if
'name:endif'))
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 165, in parse_statements
result = self.subparse(end_tokens)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 883, in subparse
rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 130, in parse_statement
return getattr(self, 'parse_' + self.stream.current.value)()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 211, in parse_if
node.test = self.parse_tuple(with_condexpr=False)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 620, in parse_tuple
args.append(parse())
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 612, in <lambda>
parse = lambda: self.parse_expression(with_condexpr=False)
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 433, in parse_expression
return self.parse_or()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 450, in parse_or
left = self.parse_and()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 459, in parse_and
left = self.parse_not()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 470, in parse_not
return self.parse_compare()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 480, in parse_compare
ops.append(nodes.Operand(token_type, self.parse_math1()))
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 496, in parse_math1
left = self.parse_concat()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 507, in parse_concat
args = [self.parse_math2()]
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 521, in parse_math2
right = self.parse_pow()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 528, in parse_pow
left = self.parse_unary()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 546, in parse_unary
node = self.parse_primary()
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 583, in parse_primary
self.fail("unexpected '%s'" % describe_token(token), token.lineno)
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\jinja2\parser.py", line 59, in fail
    raise exc(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '>'
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:19] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:19] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:19] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:19] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Dec/2018 16:50:20] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

基本的に[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/AkiyoshiOkano/items/dc19bffc88c549393699)(顔認識のWebアプリを開発している方)を参考(というかコードをほとんど引用)にしているので、Jinja2のことについてはよくわかりません。
上記のエラーに対してどう対処すればいいのか教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから判断すると、アプリケーションの`templates`ディレクトリにある'index.html'又はそれの親となっているhtmlファイルに記述ミスがあります。ミスの内容は、エラーメッセージのとおりで、予期しない（unexpected） '>' です。